# Bash - Why do these two commands in a loop run in succession rather than parallel?

Tags: bash, loops

I'm trying to pick up some bash, and I can't figure out the following behavior. I have a for loop, and it seems like one command is running through the whole loop before the other command starts even though they're within the same `do` and `done` structure. See my example:

Here's the shell script:

```
for i in "$(ls .)"
do
    printf "$i\n"
    printf "$i\n"
done
```

If this was run in a directory with the files `a`, `b`, `c` I would expect the output to be:

```
a
a
b
b
c
c
```

Instead it is:

```
a
b
c
a
b
c
```

Can anyone explain to me what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're expanding the expression in `$(ls .)` before you pass it to the loop, it's evaluating *all* the files in the directory first and then printing it twice. In essence, your loop only contains one element which you print twice.

The behaviour you want can be obtained by using the glob `*` operator instead:

```
for i in *
do
    printf "$i\n"
    printf "$i\n"
done
```

This way `*` represents a list to iterate over rather than a string that's already been evaluated.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely fixes the issue. Now I'm curious though, why is the newline in `printf` after every file then? As opposed to just after the last file name?

Comment: Good question - I'm not entirely sure myself. It almost appears the `ls` command terminates each file name with a newline character. When quoting, these are preserved. However that is obviously not the case when typing the command directly in a console. I can't answer why that behaviour happens when executed in a subshell. There's some more info about subshells here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html take a look at the second warning.

Comment: @GeorgeYates: Because `ls` prints filenames one per line *unless*  `stdout` is redirected to a terminal. In an interactive shell, it is, and you get the condensed columnized listing. See the `-1` and `-C` options to `ls` (and also `-m` and `-x` for some  more options.)

Comment: Thank you, that explains it. So much subtlety.